# Creating Batch File to search .txt files in a specific folder for a specific string, and move all files to a new folder

Tags: batch-file

Just as the title mentions, I am looking for a way to create a batch file which looks for a specific string in .txt files in a folder on my C drive. Any txt files that contain this string then need to be moved to a different folder.

I can get my batch file to find the items, I just can't figure out how to move all text files which contain the string.

---

**Update: I am now able to get the files to move, with the use of the solution, provided below.**

---

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38745804/edit) your question and format your code (pseudo and real one) properly!

Comment: Does it look better now? :)

Comment: The user added a bunch of new requirements instead of clarifying the original question. I suggest Hold as Unclear.

Comment: The original question is still there. @Squashman provided me with a solution that accommodated my original question. The only alteration was providing an update on the post, which is clearly noted.

Comment: There you go, "a bunch of new requirements" have now been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is capture the output from a command.  That is done with the FOR /F command.

```
 FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('findstr /m /C:"Thread aborted" *.txt') do (
      move "%%G" C:\backup\
      echo %%G>>logfile.txt
 )
```

Just to show you that this does work. I am running everything from the command line to show you the output.

```
C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>echo Thread aborted>file.txt

C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>dir /b
backup
file.txt

C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>FOR /F "delims=" %G in ('findstr /m /C:"Thread aborted" *.*') do @move "%G" backup
            1 file(s) moved.

C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>dir /b
backup

C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>dir /b backup\*.*
file.txt

C:\BatchFiles\Tyler>
```

Comment: Okay! I got it to work. Thanks so much for the help. My last question: Is it possible to place a conditional statement in that .batch file, and say, "if files are moved, send an email, or, record a log, or sometype of action, and if there are no files moved, then nothing happens? I tried adding an If then statement, but it is not working.

Comment: @Tyler, batch files cannot natively send emails without a 3rd party application.  You can easily create a log file of the files moved by using the echo command.  You would just echo the FOR variable and redirect the output to a file instead of the console. `echo %%G>>logfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks for all of the assistance, and prompt answers. You are very helpful!

Comment: So I have a working power shell command to send an email. Can I do something like, if(%%Gfileexisits) -insert power shell command.

Comment: @Delver, you can look at how to use a command by typing the name of the command with a `/?` after the command at the cmd prompt. `if /?`

Comment: The user asked to _looks for a specific string in .txt files_ in his question right from the start, and you were lecturing him all the time to _change the file mask_, while your answer contained the wrong file mask `*.*` to begin with, until you fixed it just 4 hours ago. Why such mismatch and lack of attention to user question?

Comment: @sambul35, because I try to teach as I go long.  If you continue to give the person the fish, they continue to ask for the fish instead of learning to fish.

Comment: You treat your own errors in answers very differently from other user answers. The asker did not say in his question that he has a directory structure in the folder with `*.txt` files, but you attacked other answers in this thread showing alternative approaches and useful for other readers down the road. You show extreme intolerance to others, and lack of objective view of your own errors.

Answer (score 0):

Save this script to *sorting.bat*, run from open Cmd Prompt, and let me know if any errors. Based on your question, you seems to have no dir structure to bypass in the folder with target files. This code will also help users, who run a similar task and need to look through dir structure:

```
@echo off
set "sourcedir=C:/Provider.Rates" & set "destindir=C:/Aborted.Threads"
for /R "%sourcedir%" %%G in (*.txt) do (
    find /i "Thread Aborted" "%%G" >nul 2>&1 && move /y "%%G" "%destindir%\%%~nxG" >nul)
echo/ & echo Sorting completed.
timeout 5
exit /b
```

Comment: @Squashman  You right about naming files. Re what the user asked for, read the edited Question. Some users don't know what they want, and never will unless debug themselves. Anyway, methods to accomplish any task vary. :)